# Android Soong: How to depend on library within APEX

Tags: android-soong

To have a shared library dependency, i need to include the following in my blueprint.

```
cc_library_shared {
    name: "libdependent",
    shared_libs: [ "libsample" ],
}
```

To include the same library in an APEX image, I need to use the following pattern.

```
apex {
    name: "sample.apex",
    native_shared_libs: ["libsample"],
}
```

How do I rewrite the rule for libdependent so it depends on the libsample within the sample.apex APEX?

The intent is to allow for upgradable libsample by including it in an APEX image.